# How to restart the node server programmatically after process.exit?

Tags: node.js, server, restart

I want the best way to restart the Node Server.

In `package.json`

I have

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

I am already using

```
process.exit(0);
```

To stop all services.

Can I restart the process? What is the best way to shut down & restart the node server?

Comment: `$ node app.js` Why are you stopping a server from inside the process itself? A server is supposed to be started or stopped by its process manager.

Comment: In a production environment, have a service manager such as `systemd` manage your node app, restarting it if/when it shuts down.